# Why does this Arduino code print "access denied"

Tags: arduino

I am having a problem with the code. whenever I show Rfid card 1 it should print welcome person 1 but with it, it prints access denied which is in the else statement it is activating the else statement after the 3000 delay of the first if statement whereas the second if statement is working fine.

Here is the code:

```
#include <deprecated.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <MFRC522Extended.h>
#include <require_cpp11.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

void setup() 
{
   Serial.begin(9600);   // Initiate a serial communication
  SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522
  Serial.println("Approximate your card to the reader...");
  Serial.println();

}
void loop() 
{
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  String content= "";
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) 
  {
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  content.toUpperCase();
  if (content.substring(1) == "C7 8B BB 4D")
  {
    Serial.println("Authorized Access,Welcome Person:1");
    Serial.println();
    delay(3000);
  }

   if (content.substring(1) == "A7 5E 63 33")
  {
    Serial.println("Authorized Access,Welcome Person:2");
    Serial.println();
    delay(3000);
  }

   else   {
    Serial.println("Access denied");
    delay(3000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an `if` statement.

Straight after that, you have another `if` statement, with its own `else`.

If you just look at the second `if`, you'll see that if it doesn't equal `"A7 5E 63 33"`, then it will print `"Access denied"`. Guess what? The first `if` is already complete, so the second `if` gets processed all by itself, and it doesn't equal that string, so the `else` gets executed.

To fix this, the first `if` *also* needs an `else` - just before the second `if`:

```
if (...) {
}
else if (...) {
}
else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `else if`

```
#include <deprecated.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <MFRC522Extended.h>
#include <require_cpp11.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Initiate a serial communication
  SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522
  Serial.println("Approximate your card to the reader...");
  Serial.println();

}
void loop() 
{
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
  {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  String content= "";
  byte letter;
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) 
  {
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
     content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
  }
  content.toUpperCase();

  if (content.substring(1) == "C7 8B BB 4D")
  {
    Serial.println("Authorized Access,Welcome Person:1");
    Serial.println();
    delay(3000);
  }

  else if (content.substring(1) == "A7 5E 63 33")
  {
    Serial.println("Authorized Access,Welcome Person:2");
    Serial.println();
    delay(3000);
  }

  else {
    Serial.println("Access denied");
    delay(3000);
  }
}
```